# How to get selected cell value of a grid view in asp.net ?

Tags: asp.net

Can any one tell me how to get a specific cell value or cell index of a selected row in grid view.
Actually i need the value of the cell in which user clicked in the grid view using asp.net.Specially how to know the cell index or column name(index) which is clicked by user.
Please help me out.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? What are they going to click on and what do you want to have happen when they click on it?

Comment: thnks for response.i need to reload another grid view based on the value of the clicked cell value of a grid view.

Comment: So, you want to post back to the same page with the value and index of the column?

Comment: I provided an answer. This was done without an IDE or tested, so there may be some syntax issues. If there are, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't think there is anything built into the asp.net grid view to do this, we can use a little javascript to handle the event, setting a few hidden fields, then clicking a asp submit button.

To start, add the following in your aspx page, inside of the form tag

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ClickedColumnIndex" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ClickedRowIndex" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ClickedValue" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="GridViewClickedButton" 
    OnClick="GridViewClickedButton_Click" style="visibility:hidden;" />
```

Then we will want to add a script tag with some javascript in it.
Since I don't know the ID of your gridview, I will use "mygridview". Just replace it will the actual ID.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function initializeGridViewClick(){

    // get the gridview table object
    var tbl = document.getElementById('<%=mygridview.ClientID %>');

    //get the table rows (TR) inside of the table body (TBODY)
    var trs = tbl.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

    //loop through each of the rows 
    for (var row = 0; row < trs.length; row++) {

      // get all of the cells in the row
      var tds = trs[row].getElementsByTagName('td');

      //loop through each of the cells
      for (var cell = 0; cell < tds.length; cell++) {

        // set the cell's click function, passing in the row index, cell index, and the HTML in the cell
        tds[cell].onclick = function(){ cellClicked(row, cell, this.innerHTML); };
      }
    }
  }

  function cellClicked(row_idx, col_idx, val){

    //set the values of the hidden fields we added earlier
    document.getElementById('<%=ClickedColumnIndex.ClientID %>').value = row_idx;
    document.getElementById('<%=ClickedRowIndex.ClientID %>').value = col_idx;
    document.getElementById('<%=ClickedValue.ClientID %>').value = val;

    //now perform the click on the submit button we added earlier
    document.getElementById('<%=GridViewClickedButton.ClientID %>').click();

  }

  //now we set it up so the initialization function runs when the form is loaded
  window.onload=function(){initializeGridViewClick();};

</script>
```

Now, in your server code, just add the following into the Page_Load handler to wire up the button event and provide a handler for the button's click event, then perform whatever steps you want with the column index, row index, and value.

**C#**

inside of your Page Load method, add the following

```
GridViewClickedButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.GridViewClickedButton_Click);
```

now add the method to handle the click

```
void GridViewClickedButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  // Now we can call a function with our new values
  MyFunction(ClickedColumnIndex.Value, ClickedRowIndex.Value, ClickedValue.Value);
}
```

**VB**

now add the method to handle the click

```
Sub GridViewClickedButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
{
  // Now we can call a function with our new values
  MyFunction(ClickedColumnIndex.Value, ClickedRowIndex.Value, ClickedValue.Value)
}
```

**The result**

When a user clicks on a cell within the gridview's table body, the following will occur:

1. the javascript `cellClicked` function will set the column index, row index, and value of the cell, then click the hidden asp:Button
2. which will post back to the server and fire GridViewClickedButton_Click

Comment: thanks for response.But in the above code,Can u plz tell me when does GridViewClickedButton_Click event will fire ?

Comment: The button should fire when the a cell in the table is clicked, after the values in the hidden inputs are set.

Comment: but i tried,button click event is not fired,anything missed here ?

Comment: I guess we will need to determine where it is not working. Are you getting any browser errors? You could place an `alert('im here');` inside of the cellClicked function to see if it is making it there. If you want to send me the HTML it outputs, I could look at it.